# I wonder whether Big data can be into the node on AgensGraph

Tags: bigdata, agens-graph

As a title, I wonder whether Big data can be into the node. 
Also, I'd like to know whether there's any capacity limitation and 
it's possible to put the large value as one value into the vertex. 
Eg) Will it be okay to put Datatype:binary to the value?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the value of vertex can be stored as a property.
This property is stores as jsonb type internally. And the maximum size of jsonb object is about 256MB. 
When the title: ""value"" is stored, 'value' data being allowed internally in jsonb can be categorized into four types such as **numeric, text, null and object.** 
Big data can be stored as a text type. But its tolerance range should be considered.